# Solana Account and fees

Tags: account, fees

What is the transaction fees for creating a Solana account created by using CLI command "solana-keygen new" and how to pay that one time account creation fee?

How much SOL I need to transfer to this Solana account to get rent exempted for one year ?

If I transfer more SOL to this Solana account from my trading account, then can I transfer the SOL back to the trading wallet account?

Comment: `solana-keygen new` creates a new keypair, not a Solana account perse. You pay no fee for that bit.

Comment: If I create a solana wallet account via Rust by using instruction solana_program::system_instruction::create_account(...)
The 3rd parameter is the nr. of exempted amount of lamport, in the end it's SOL. How to pay that?
//Build instruction for create account 
let create_token_acc_ix = solana_program::system_instruction::create_account(
 &payer_pubkey,
 &wallet_pubkey,
 rent,
 space as u64,
 &spl_token::ID,
);

Answer (score 0):

You need sol on your main account to pay the one time fee and be rent exempt
You can use Solana cli to calculate the amount of sol that should be on your account to be rent exempt